# add/delete ubuntu specific folder or file right click context using bash

Tags: gnome, kernel, nautilus, filesystem, fstab

I want to change the right click context menu of ubuntu specific  folder using bash script. When bash script executes, it first create a file or folder having only two right click context menu option.

```
Mount
Unmount
```